# Why don't we use Ampere's law to find the magnetic field due to a wire of finite length?

Tags: magnetic-fields

So, when the current carrying wire is infinitely long, we apply Ampere's circuital law. But if the wire has a certain length, then we use Biot-Savart law. My question is, what is wrong with using Ampere's law?

Comment: I suggest you go through this explanation for your query : https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/amperes-law-must-the-current-extend-to-infinity.118298/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampere's law is always true, but it is not always helpful. The expression for Ampere's law is:

$$ \oint\vec B\cdot d\vec l=\mu_0I$$

In the case of an infinite wire, we can make arguments, based on symmetries of the problem, that for a circular loop centered on the wire, $\vec B$ is constant and parallel to $d\vec l$, and so this expression simplifies to:

$$ 2\pi rB=\mu_0I\rightarrow B={\mu_0I\over2\pi r}$$

which gives us the magnitude of the $B$-field everywhere, without having to do any non-trivial integrals.

With a finite wire, there are fewer symmetries. You can still use Ampere's law, but without the symmetries it actually involves *more* math than just using the Biot-Savart law directly.